# gcc can't take constexpr address of attribute through member pointer?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, g++, constexpr

I'm trying to take the address of an object's attribute through a member pointer at compile-time. The following code compiles fine on MSVC but not on GCC:

```
#include <optional>

struct S {
    int i = 42;
};

int main() {
    constexpr S obj;
    constexpr auto member = &S::i;
    constexpr auto ptr = std::optional(member);

    // OK
    constexpr auto value = obj.*(*ptr);
    static_assert(value == 42);

    // Doesn't compile on gcc, can't take address through member pointer
    constexpr auto & attr = obj.*(*ptr);
    static_assert(attr == obj.i);
}
```

GCC gives the following error:

```
<source>:17:39: error: '(const int&)(& obj)' is not a constant expression
17 |     constexpr auto & attr = obj.*(*ptr);
```

Here's the code on compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/4WhW3qd7c

I haven't been able to find information about which compiler is wrong here. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of a glvalue constant expression can only refer to an object with static storage duration.

`obj` doesn't have static storage duration, because it is declared at block scope.

You can give `obj` static storage duration by adding the `static` keyword at block scope:

```
static constexpr S obj;
```

or by declaring it at namespace scope.

Comment: Thanks! So MSVC was being too permissive